# How to print lines from stdin?

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

I'm redirecting stdin to be output produced from the command ls -l when run on the command line, and I want to print out its results.

So say after I run ls -l I get the following output:

```
total 519
-rw-------  1 jeff  dev    1274 22 Jun 14:52 prinprog
-rwx---xr--  1 jeff  dev   2410  6 Apr 12:10 temp.txt
-rwxr----x  1 jeff  dev    8128  1 Feb  2013 yyz
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  dev      98 15 Feb  2013 yyz.c
```

Now after compiling my C program I do ls -l | ./testing and I have effectively changed the stdin from being the keyboard to what ever output was produced by the ls -l command. Now what I want to do in my C program is print out the output produced by the ls -l command.

I do that by scanf() and a while loop. What I'm having trouble with is formatting my text. That first line "total 519" is kind of useless to me but its throwing me off.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

char permissions[10];
int num;
char user[20];
char random[20];
int fileSize;

while(scanf("%s %d %s %s %d", permissions, &num, user, random, &fileSize) != EOF) {
    printf("%s %d %s %s %d\n", permissions, num, user, random, fileSize);
}

return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Read lines with `fgets()` — `char buffer[4096]; fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);`.  Read the first line and ignore it.  Then read the other lines and parse them with `sscanf()` after they've been read.  Your format doesn't read the date or name information, so that will be left in the input to be processed (not very successfully) by the next call to `scanf()`.

Comment: You're not checking the return value from `scanf` properly. `scanf` can return things other than `EOF` and "success".

Comment: `scanf` `%s` is a buffer overflow waiting to happen. Never use it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happened to the line with `temp.txt`?  It looks like you go an extra `-` in the permissions part.

Answer (score 1):

A proposal :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  static char line[256];

  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != NULL) {
    char perms[11];
    int nlinks;
    char user[20];
    char grp[20];
    int size;
    char month[10];
    int day;
    char time[10];
    char name[256];

   if (sscanf(line, "%10s %d %19s %19s %d %9s %d %9s %255s",
               perms, &nlinks, user, grp, &size, month, &day, time, name) == 9)
       printf("perms=%s nlinks=%d user=%s grp=%s size=%d month=%s date=%d time/year=%s name=%s\n",
         perms, nlinks, user, grp, size, month, day, time, name);
  }

  return 0;  
}
```

Execution example :

```
ls -l /usr/sbin | ./a.out
perms=-rwxr-xr-x nlinks=1 user=root grp=root size=9788 month=déc. date=13 time/year=2016 name=accessdb
perms=-rwxr-xr-x nlinks=1 user=root grp=root size=3078 month=oct. date=5 time/year=22:43 name=addgnupghome
perms=lrwxrwxrwx nlinks=1 user=root grp=root size=7 month=juin date=27 time/year=2016 name=addgroup
perms=-rwxr-xr-x nlinks=1 user=root grp=root size=860 month=avril date=2 time/year=2017 name=add-shell
perms=-rwxr-xr-x nlinks=1 user=root grp=root size=34509 month=juin date=27 time/year=2016 name=adduser
perms=-rwxr-xr-x nlinks=1 user=root grp=root size=4136 month=janv. date=23 time/year=2017 name=alsabat-test
perms=-rwxr-xr-x nlinks=1 user=root grp=root size=83912 month=janv. date=23 time/year=2017 name=alsactl
perms=-rwxr-xr-x nlinks=1 user=root grp=root size=27872 month=janv. date=23 time/year=2017 name=alsa-info
perms=-rwxr-xr-x nlinks=1 user=root grp=root size=2219 month=oct. date=5 time/year=22:43 name=applygnupgdefaults
perms=-rwxr-xr-x nlinks=1 user=root grp=root size=44224 month=déc. date=26 time/year=2016 name=arp
perms=-rwxr-xr-x nlinks=1 user=root grp=root size=42920 month=nov. date=24 time/year=2017 name=arpd
perms=-rwxr-xr-x nlinks=1 user=root grp=root size=13542 month=oct. date=10 time/year=2016 name=aspell-autobuildhash
perms=-rwxr-xr-x nlinks=1 user=root grp=root size=17884 month=déc. date=8 time/year=2016 name=atd
perms=-rwxr-xr-x nlinks=1 user=root grp=root size=105136 month=janv. date=23 time/year=2017 name=avahi-daemon
...
```